# How to use Pivot table in non-numeric values?

Tags: python, pivot-table

I am working with Pivot function in Pandas:

My input table is:

```
POI_Entity_ID            State
ADD_Q319_143936     Rajasthan
Polyline-Kot-2089       New Delhi 
Q111267412          Rajasthan 
EL_Q113_32573       Rajasthan 
RCE_UDZ_10979           New Delhi
```

I want my output as:

```
Sate          counts of POI_Entity_ID
Rajasthan      3
New Delhi      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of rows in each group using the `pandas.DataFrame.value_counts()`.

In your case it would look something like:

```py
d = {'State': ['Rajasthan','New Delhi','Rajasthan','Rajasthan','New Delhi'], 'POI_Entity_ID': ['ADD_Q319_143936','Polyline-Kot-2089','Q111267412','EL_Q113_32573','RCE_UDZ_10979']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['State'].value_counts()
```

The last line produces the following table:

```py
Rajasthan    3
New Delhi    2
```

You can also use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby()` combined with the `count()` method:

```py
df.groupby('State').count()
```

yields the following table:

```py
           POI_Entity_ID
State                   
New Delhi              2
Rajasthan              3
```

Comment: I working on huge data set nearly 200K data , it was just example so can we address it with Pivot table or some another technique.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not think that it influences the answer I gave you. It will work on a data frame with 200k rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot table and aggregator function as count, keeping your index as 'State'.

```
d ={'POI_Entity_ID':  ['ADD_Q319_143936','Polyline-Kot-2089','Q111267412','EL_Q113_32573',
'RCE_UDZ_10979'], 'State':['Rajasthan', 'New Delhi' ,'Rajasthan',
'Rajasthan' ,'New Delhi']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

pivotdf=pd.pivot_table(data=df,index='State',values='POI_Entity_ID',aggfunc='count')
```

gives you a table like :

```
           POI_Entity_ID
State                   
New Delhi              2
Rajasthan              3
```